# How to pass additional parameters to validator->after function in Laravel 8.x?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8.x version.

As we know that we may also attach callbacks to be run after validation is completed. This allows us to easily perform further validation and even add more error messages to the message collection. We can call the `after` method on a `validator` instance:

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);

$validator->after(function ($validator) {
    if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
        $validator->errors()->add(
            'field', 'Something is wrong'
        );
    }
});

if ($validator->fails()) {
    //
}
```

but I want to use a `$customVariable` in this `after` function like:

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);

$customVariable = 'not happy';

$validator->after(function ($validator, $customVariable) {
    if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
        $validator->errors()->add(
            'field', 'Something is wrong because you are ' . $customVariable
        );
    }
});

if ($validator->fails()) {
    //
}
```

Is there anyone who can suggest me how can we pass and use custom variables / parameters in `$validator->after()` function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit variables from the parent scope with the `use` keyword ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)). Something like this should work:

```
$validator = Validator::make(...);

$customVariable = 'not happy';

$validator->after(function ($validator) use ($customVariable) {
    if ($this->somethingElseIsInvalid()) {
        $validator->errors()->add(
            'field', 'Something is wrong because you are ' . $customVariable
        );
    }
});

if ($validator->fails()) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear @szaman szaman. This is similar like when we use multiple `orWhere` conditions and want to pass conditional parameters. Your solution worked. Thanks :)